# How to simplify recursive eq?

Tags: summation, recursion

I know how to programatically calculate this, but im not sure how it can be simplified for documentation.
Can someone help?

$R = (X\cdot 1) + (X\cdot 2) + (X\cdot 3) + (X\cdot 4) + (X\cdot 5) + (X\cdot 6) + ...$ etc, repeated up to a value of $Y$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE. Be sure to include context and what your own thoughts/work are on your questions to be sure your questions don't get closed.

Comment: Thanks. Im a simple software programmer, as i said i know how to solve this programmatically, but have no idea how it can be simplified and properly described in documentation.

Comment: Isn't that just $$R=X \sum_{j=1}^{Y}j$$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is $R = (X\cdot 1) + (X\cdot 2) + (X\cdot 3) + (X\cdot 4) + (X\cdot 5) + (X\cdot 6) + ...+X\cdot \color{blue}{Y}$, then this formula might help: $\sum_{i=0}^Y Xi=X\sum_{i=0}^Y i=X\frac{Y\cdot (Y+1)}{2}$

Comment: That does seem to do the job, thankyou! Unless this can be simplified further, ill take this as an answer.

Comment: @thecoder A derivation of the formula can be checked here: http://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/